# Iterating the dates in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am developing an application for reporting and analytic,where I need to generate data on a daily basis and put it in a CSV.To be more clear, if I take the report today like day one any how I can get the report thats already done, if I get the report tomorrow I should be able to get the data of today,yesterday. If i take after 4 days I should get the report starting from day 1 to day 4.

How it can be done. Looking for heads up

Comment: Inside a rails app or a simple ruby script via cron job?

Comment: You want the data to be generated and set to mail or display new data every day? Can the data from the day before be generated today if it wasn't generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
today = Date.today
tomorrow = today.next
four_days_ago = 4.days.ago(today)
four_days_later = 4.days.since(today)
(today..(4.days.since(today)).each {|d| puts d}
```