# Iterating through Dates in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm writing a method that iterates using dates given a start and end date, and I need to the date within the loop.  Something like this:

```
start_date = 2013/03/12
end_date = 2013/11/20

# from start_date to end_date do |f|
  puts date_this_iteration_is_processing
end
```

Can someone please help me with this?

I've read these questions, but they didn't indicate how to determine the date that the given iteration is on.

[How to Loop through Months in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13898795/how-to-loop-through-months-in-ruby-on-rails)
[Iterating the dates in ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770151/iterating-the-dates-in-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

is this what you are looking for?
use the range operator `..`

```
start_date = Date.parse('2013-03-12')
end_date = Date.parse('2013-11-20')

(start_date..end_date).each do |day|
  puts day
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `upto`

```
start_date = Date.parse('2019-05-20')
end_date = Date.parse('2019-05-22')

(start_date).upto(end_date).each do |day|
  puts day
end
```

Answer (score 2):

In a less static fashion:

```
(Date.today - 60.days..Date.today).each do |day|
  puts day
end
```